# PHP + Javascript dynamic div for dynamically adding inputs in form

Tags: php, javascript, dynamic, html

dynamically adds more dropdownlist that is populated with data from MySQL to div on button click.

```
<div id="dynamicDiv"><p>
        sqlconn();
        $sql="SELECT column_name FROM table";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        echo "<select type=\"column_name\">";       
        for($i=0;$i<$num_rows;$i++){
            $table = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            echo "<option value='" . $table['column_name'] . "'>" . $table['column_name'] . "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
        mysql_close($con);
</div>

<input type="button" value="+ Data" onClick="addInput('dynamicDiv');">
```

the only method i know is by writing a script but i can't do any php scripting on the script (or i can?). need to query to populate added drop down list.

```
var counter = 1;
var limit = 15;
function addInput(divName){
     if (counter == limit)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
     }
     else {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "whatever needs to be dynamically input on div";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++;
     }
}
```

is there a workaround to populate the dropdownlist in the script? much appreciated!

Comment: what are you actually asking - here's my attempt at an: use ajax request data from server traverse returned data appending to dom as required would you like me to be more explicit? if so please ask an actual question

Comment: how do i go about using AJAX to populate the div?

Comment: using jquery's [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) you can implement the logic to update elements a bit like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7tsXv/) within the success function, else if using your own implementation of [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX/Getting_Started) you can handle it in `onreadystatechange`

Comment: thank you for your help! but how do i go to the database and get the data in ajax? im unable to do so in my script because there's php sqlconnection, query and array to pass to the script.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have 2 options

- Create the HTML for the dropdown list when creating the page and do something like

as in

```
<script type=...>
var selecthtml='<?php echo $selecthtml; ?>'
function addInput(divName){
     if (counter == limit)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
     }
     else {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = selecthtml;
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++;
     }
}
</script>
```

- Or look at AJAX to populate your select.

The former is easier, the latter is cleaner.

Comment: don't mind telling me how do i go about doing on AJAX? i'm googling as well.

Comment: Its not so hard after all: You'd have to create a PHP method, that gives back eitehr the options only (in JSON Form) or the HTML directly. Use a framework (Dojo? jQuery?) for the AJAX call itself. If you get the HTML just do ....innerHTML=whatever_you_got. IF you got the options, create a select in DOM and then create option objects and add them to the select's options collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
**This is the actual way the test goes and Change according to your table and use it . It will work as you expected**
```

";
    echo 'countStud ='.count($arrayData).';';
    echo 'stud = '.json_encode($arrayData).';';
    echo "";

    ?>

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    divCount =0;   
    function createDiv()
    {  

        var divTag  = document.createElement("div");
        var studList ="";
         studList += '<select id="BOX_'+divCount+'" name="BOX_'+divCount+'">';
         studList += '<option value="">--- Select ---</option>';
                     for(i=0;i<countStud;i++){
                        studList += '<option value="'+stud[i].stud_id+'">'+stud[i].stud_name+'</option>';
                     }
         studList += '</select>';
         divTag.innerHTML  = studList;
        document.getElementById('dynamicElements').appendChild(divTag);
        divCount++;

    }

 </script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" method="post">
<div id="dynamicElements"></div>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
 <input type="button" onClick="createDiv()" value="Add"/>
</body>
</html>
```